Property ownerState does not exist on type { theme: unknown; } MUI5
i want to customize MUI theme and error :
Ts error  Property  ownerState  does not exist on type  { theme: unknown; } 
type BageThemeStyles = {
    defaultProps?: ComponentsProps['MuiBadge'];
    styleOverrides?: ComponentsOverrides['MuiBadge'];
    variants?: ComponentsVariants['MuiBadge'];
};

let badgeThemeStyle = (theme: typeof lighthouseTheme): BageThemeStyles => {
    return {
        variants: [
            {
                props: { variant: 'dot' },
                style: ({ ownerState }) => {
                    const size: 'string' = ownerState.size || 'md';
                    return {
                        [`& .${badgeClasses.dot}`]: {
                            // @ts-ignore
                            height: badgeDotSizeObj[size],
                            // @ts-ignore
                            minWidth: badgeDotSizeObj[size],
                            // @ts-ignore
                            borderRadius: badgeDotBorderObj[size]
                        }
                    };
                }
            }
        ]
    };
};




how to fix that or added ownerState  type  to theme.
